# remove dir with files not working

Tags: mac, unix, terminal

I'm trying to remove this directory pear from my *tmp* folder, but it's not letting me.

I tried
`sudo rm -r pear`

But then it asks me to override, and I put `y` and it says *Permission denied*. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for pear/cache/0758c6bb0294a8697ed0d0f483ffbb80rest.cachefile? y
rm: pear/cache/0758c6bb0294a8697ed0d0f483ffbb80rest.cachefile: Permission denied
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for pear/cache/0758c6bb0294a8697ed0d0f483ffbb80rest.cacheid? y
rm: pear/cache/0758c6bb0294a8697ed0d0f483ffbb80rest.cacheid: Permission denied
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for pear/cache/09f3c0d5c6071dd733b69a3cf51e1496rest.cachefile?
```

Comment: have you tried adding the flag f?

Comment: @davogotland, no I haven't. Does it go at the end?

Comment: @davogotland I'm not familiar with how to add that flag

Comment: oh! sorry :) you're currently using one flag: r. the flags are preceded by a dash. so adding the f flag would look like this: rm -rf. your full command would be `sudo rm -rf pear`. the f flag removes any questions you would normally be asked. this makes using the f flag kind of risky. be careful when you use it! :)

Comment: The first step is to look at the permissions and see what's going on.  Try `ls -leOa pear/cache` to view the full permissions and file flags on the files and the directory they're in.